# Надеюсь, ... / Надеюсь, что

Tags: синтаксис, вводные-слова, синтаксический-разбор

Прочитала на этом сайте, что "Надеюсь, ..." это обособленное вводное предложение. Скажите пожалуйста, правильно считать, если добавить союз "что", то вторая часть предложения из простого предложения превратится в дополнительное предложение?

> Надеюсь, *всё обойдётся.*
>
> Надеюсь, **что** *всё обойдётся.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Глагол **надеюсь** может выступать в роли вводного слова, не являясь членом предложения, и показывать отношение говорящего к высказываемой мысли (неуверенность, предположение, неопределённость, допущение). Может играть в предложении и роль сказуемого.

К вводным словам такого значения относятся: наверное, кажется, вероятно, возможно, пожалуй, думаю, полагаю, предположим, допустим и др.

**Надеюсь, всё обойдётся** (простое предложение; вводное слово можно опустить).

**Надеюсь, что всё обойдётся** (сложноподчиненное предложение с союзом *что*; главная часть – односоставное определённо-личное предложение, опущено подлежащее **я**; слово "надеюсь" нельзя изъять из предложения).

Надеюсь, мы не опоздаем из-за пробок на самолёт.
[Я] Надеюсь, что мы не опоздаем из-за пробок на самолёт.

Надеюсь, вам понравилось в нашем городе.
[Я] Надеюсь, что вам понравилось в нашем городе.

Полезную информацию о вводных словах и сочетаниях можно посмотреть [**здесь**](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/726-210_vvodnye_slova__slovosochetaniya_i_predlozheniya.html).

Comment: Всё так, только " Надеюсь"  -  не неполное, а односоставное определённо-личное  предложение.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение. Могу ли я внести правку, используя Ваш комментарий (для получения полного и правильного ответа)?

Comment: Конечно, ответ должен быть верным.

Comment: _Надеюсь, мы не опоздаем из-за (автомобильных) пробок на самолёт._ В разговорной речи такие определения обычно опускаюся, особенно тогда, когда люди уже находятся в этой самой пробке. Полное предложение такое:  Надеюсь, мы не опоздаем из-за этих ужасных пробок на самолёт.

Comment: большое спасибо всем за ответ! один вопрос: если добавить подлежащие "я" → "я надеюсь, всё обойдётся" первая часть предложения все равно будет считаться как вводное слово или уже как самостоятельное предложение?

Comment: Конечно, самостоятельное. Вопрос: - Мы успеем на самолет? Ответ: - Я надеюсь.

Answer (score 2):

**Надеюсь, что всё обойдётся.**

При наличии союза ЧТО это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным (я надеюсь, что всё обойдется).

**Надеюсь, всё обойдется.** Это простое предложение, осложненное вводной конструкцией.

Comment: Jasmin, извините, пожалуйста, можно задать Вам еще один вопрос, чтобы закрепить правильно ли я поняла: такое предложение "Я надеюсь, я вас не слишком напугал" будет считаться как бессоюзное сложное?

Comment: Я надеюсь,  я... Это вводное предложение. В БСП для выражения изъяснительных отношений используется тире или двоеточие (более сильные знаки, чем запятая)

Comment: Jasmin, cпасибо за ответ, но uffff запуталась... В предыдущем комментарии от user Римма Михайлова было сказано, "я надеюсь" самостоятельное предложение. Думала, что если добавить субъект "я", можно считать это kak самостоятельнoe предложение со своим субъектом и предикатом... ufffiii

Comment: Существуют самостоятельные предложения, которые используются в качестве ответной реплики в диалоге: Надеюсь (односоставное). Я надеюсь (двусоставное). Но если эти предложения входят в состав сложного предложения и отделяются запятой,  то они оба являются вводными. Сравним: Я надеялся: когда нибудь всё изменится. Это уже БСП с изъяснительным значением, ставится двоеточие.